# Storing image in database vs storing in file system

Tags: php, database, image, blob

I am working on a online shopping website, it will have product images also. I have confusion regarding were i should store images. If I store these images in the database image url must be kept into the database and if i store image in blob format i have to decode it before using in php. Can anyone tell which one will be better choice?

Comment: Store the image on the filesystem and the URL in the database.

Comment: Oh, btw. Please read this also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best solution is to keep the Database clean of any images. Below are number of reasons -

- Database will soon start to grow
- File system is good for storing files
- You have put extra effort to decode them in PHP(Resource overhead)
- Many databases I have studied keep the images in the File System (WordPress source)

Hope it helps

Comment: +1 for this point. "You have put extra effort to decode them in PHP(Resource overhead)"